# Git - Pull request with current changes but not previous commits

Tags: git, github, git-pull, pull-request

I created a branch from an origin, and made changes on that branch. I made several commits to show a friend what I was doing, but I don't want these commits to show up on the origin when I make a pull request.

How can I make it so only one commit will show up on the pull request.

What I was thinking about doing was creating another branch, and resetting my previous branch to head.... But I don't really know what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is to ***squash*** the commits on the branch.

This can be done by (in the new branch that you want to modify) type the following:

```
$ git rebase -i <your_starting_commit_SHA>
```

And then you'll be able to either `pick` or `squash` the commits (or reword a commit so that it matches a more appropriate commit message after the squashing).

When you do this interactive rebase, you will be confronted with the following:

```
pick <commit1_SHA> <commit1_message>
pick <commit2_SHA> <commit2_message>
pick <commit3_SHA> <commit3_message>
pick <commit4_SHA> <commit4_message>
# ... so on and so forth
```

If you want to squash all of your commits into your original one, then you would keep `pick` for the first commit, and then change the remaining `pick`s to `squash`.  Git would then squash `commit2`, `commit3`, and `commit4`, into `commit1` therefore giving you your *clean* commit history before your pull request.

The end result here would be a **single** commit with your reworded commit message, instead of the original four commits (used for illustration purposes, of course).

Comment: Also see here: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

Suppose that your cloned branched from origin is called A. I would clone the origin again into a new branch called B. Then I would merge the A branch into the B branch, using the --squash flag (while on branch B: git merge --squash A), so all of your commits in Branch A, would go to Branch B as one. Then you can issue a pull request from your B branch